# What are the acceptable delay values for receiving BSM, WSA, and WSM messages in Veins(OMNET++) simulator?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using the default example of Veins to record the delay in receiving BSM, WSA, and WSM messages.
In the onBSM(), onWSA(), and onWSM() functions, I am emitting a signal with the difference between the current time and the creation time of the message.

```
emit(mSigBSMdelay,simTime().dbl()-bsm->getCreationTime().dbl());
```

I recorded an average of 0.0003s for BSM, 0.00007s for WSA, and 0.5s for WSM. I understand that the BSM and WSA messages are sent over the control channel, while the WSM is sent over the service channel if the "dataOnSch" parameter is set to True.
I believe having 0.5s delay for receiving the WSM is a lot. Moreover, the Veins example schedules sending WSM using:

```
 scheduleAt(computeAsynchronousSendingTime(1, ChannelType::service), wsm);
```

Is the setting of the line above optimal?